# Difference between bagging and pasting?

Tags: machine-learning, bagging, pasting

I found the definition:

```
Bagging is to use the same training for every predictor, but to train them on 
different random subsets of the training set. 
When sampling is performed with replacement, this method is 
called bagging (short for bootstrap aggregating). 
When sampling is performed without replacement, it is called pasting.
```

What is "replacement" in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a sampling unit is drawn from a finite population and is returned
> to that population, after its characteristic(s) have been recorded,
> before the next unit is drawn, the sampling is said to be “with
> replacement”. In the contrary case the sampling is “without
> replacement”.

Source: [OECD Glossary of Statistical Terms](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=3835#:%7E:text=OECD%20Glossary%20of%20Statistical%20Terms%20%2D%20Sampling%20with%20replacement%20Definition&text=Definition%3A,to%20be%20%E2%80%9Cwith%20replacement%E2%80%9D.)